# Is it possible to find out which sectors are pending without full disk read?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, sectors

I want to get a list of sectors that are reported as pending in the S.M.A.R.T. value 197 (С5) Current Pending Sector Count. Any chance to get it without resorting to a full surface scan?

Comment: What are you going to do with the list if you get it?

Comment: @DavidPostill, I'm going to try to remap them via Victoria HDD. I've already recovered this way a couple of soft bads that I encountered during the short self-test, and I want to try to fix all of them. Then I'll know whether they were all soft bads. If yes, they were caused by power outages and the disk is healthy. If not, they should be remapped and maybe there is a reason to worry.

Comment: What does the rest of the smart data look like? Can you [edit] and include all the smart results?

Comment: @DavidPostill: Sorry, but I feel that it would be off-topic for the question and will not help anyone else in the future. Thank you for trying to help though, maybe we should bring this discussion to the chat?

Comment: Please read https://www.backblaze.com/blog/what-smart-stats-indicate-hard-drive-failures/